# Change the background color with region text as color code

Tags: faces, text-properties

I have many color variables defined in my css - LESS file, whose background color i like to highlight on text selection and running this elisp block.

```
(add-text-properties
 (region-beginning)
 (region-end) 
 '(:background (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))))
```

When i chose the word, `#ea7600` in this LESS code and eval the above elisp code,

```
@rw-orange:         **#ea7600**;
@rw-orange-dark:    #ce6006;
@rw-orange-light:   #fff5cc;
```

It didn't change the text's background to orange color. How can i make such a change and persist it too for all future sessions?

Comment: You need to specify that the text property you want to add is property `face` (or `font-lock-face`, depending on what you are trying to do). But why not just customize face `region`, using `M-x customize-face RET region`?

Comment: i like the new color to remain, even when the selection gets removed....

Comment: I see. Now the question makes more sense. You still need to add `face` to your `add-text-properties` call, however.